# Apache 403 Forbidden problems with certain folder only on DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, permissions, http-status-code-403, document-root, windows-2003-webserver

I am receiving 403 Apache Forbidden errors when I set my documentroot in:

> C:\Google%20Drive\public_html

But it works ok when I put

> C:\public_html

I think the problem is due Windows folder permissions, but I tried to copy as the good one and it seems to be exact. Please see attached screenshoot. It seems to be ok but it does not work
[image: attached screenshoot]

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried removing the Space on Google[SPACE]Drive? Windows does not like URL-Tags in Foldernames.

Comment: Yes, but it does not work! I tried to move this folder out of Google Drive main directory and it fails again. It seems something weird with that folder? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my self the solucion. It is changing the folder to another folder. If not this was impossible... Thanks who tried to help me.